# jcifs login order

Tags: samba, jcifs

I am using Samba jcifs API to access Windows shares from a Java program, I successfully log in with the string   `"smb://a.com;administrator:password@10.0.0.89/shared/"`.

After I change to a non-existent domain I can still log in successfully, this is also the same for workgroup.

I want to know how jcifs processes authentication.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it depend on samba server configuration.